# What is the best way to access lookup values in symfony? On the database or constants?

Tags: symfony1, yaml, lookup

I am creating a web project and want it to be optimized. Instead of accessing lookup values in the database (to minimize access), I think it should be stored somewhere in symfony. What is the best way to this? In YML with PHP Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option I use for values that should never change and that are not environment-specific is to define constants in a relevant model or helper class.

The advantages are:

1) if you name those constants well using them helps make the code more self-documenting

2) if you use an IDE with autocompletion features it will look up and verify their names as you're coding.

3) they are the fastest possible method of lookup.

Answer (score 3):

You can put values that don't change often in lib/app.yml

You can access those values by using sfConfig::get('value').

app.yml is cool because you can store enviroment specific values in it.

Comment: and it gets cached so it is fast